# Поиск даты в базе данных без учёта доли секунд

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework

Здравствуйте. В моём приложении есть база данных. Есть таблица с колонкой типа `DateTime`. В code-behind при создании объекта есть свойство Date типа `DateTime`. Данное свойство я инициализирую таким образом: `Date = DateTime.Now`. Для работы с базой данных в code-behind я использую технологию Entity Framework, подход к проектированию приложения Model First.

Далее, как только я сохраняю информацию в базу данных, у меня в БД у этой колонки (Date) записывается дата, и у этой даты есть доли секунды, например: 2018-03-18 15:43:00,667.

Как сделать так, чтобы поиск даты был без учёта доли секунды, если это возможно, конечно? Например, есть две даты: `2018-03-18 15:43:00,667` и `2018-03-18 15:43:00,122`. В приложении есть фильтр, я указываю значение `Вс, 18 мар 2018 15:43:00 GMT` и мне нужно, чтобы вот эти две даты выводились в качестве результата поиска.

В базе данных я пробовал у колонки поменять тип данных на `smalldatetime`, доли секунды у даты пропали, всё как нужно, но при создании записи в базе данных, секунды у этих дат почему-то всегда равны нулю, что не совсем нравится это всё.

Comment: Какая именно база данных? Укажите в тегах. С помощью какой технологии работаете с этой СУБД? Какая-то ORM? Отредактируйте вопрос.

Comment: "секунды у этих дат почему-то всегда равны нулю" - т.е. всё работает согласно документации ;) https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/data-types/smalldatetime-transact-sql

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov обновил свой вопрос. Последнее предложение в первом абзаце.

Comment: @АндрейNOP в том и дело, что я читал документацию на msdn перед тем, как задать вопрос. Поленился примеры посмотреть. В этой статье меня в самой первой таблице смутил раздел "Диапазон времени", где чётко указано, что диапазон времени от 00:00:00 до 23:59:59. Поэтому я был немного в замешательстве, почему у меня нет секунд.

Comment: @Cuurjol, раз у вас EF, вам прекрасно подойдет ответ `@Athari

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Проверка на равенство без долей секунд" — это проверка на попадание в диапазон значений.

```
DateTime dateFrom = GetRoundDateFromInput();
DateTime dateTo = dateFrom.AddSeconds(1);
db.Foos.Where(f => dateFrom <= f.Date && f.Date < dateTo);
```