# DateTime.CompareTo() можно ли сделать сравнение без учета миллисекунд?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

`DateTime.CompareTo(Date)` сравнивает экземпляр из базы данных, и `Date`-данные которые пришли от клиента. Проблема в том, что Date от клиента не имеет миллисекунд. Тут получается, что нужно либо сравнивать без миллисекунд, либо как то отправлять клиенту `POST` запросом Дату с миллисекундами(что нежелательно).

Comment: `dateTime1.Date.CompareTo(dateTime2.Date);`?

Comment: свойство Date полностью отбрасывает час минуту секунду и миллисекунду. Мне нужно чтобы отбрасывались только миллисекунды

Comment: Создайте новые даты из старых и новые сравнивайте, просто при создании не указывайте миллисекунды

Comment: Да этот метод хорош. Но в моем случае я использую лямбда выражение`foreach(var i in db.i.where(i=>i.Date.CompareTo(Date)>0))`. Хотя этот метод можно использовать инициируя данные без миллисекунд. Сначала создать `DateTime date= DateTime.Now`, а потом скопировать все кроме миллисекунд. Спасибо

Comment: Возможный дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/800987/218063

Answer (score 1):

Можно сравнить так:

```
if (Math.Abs((date1 - date2).TotalSeconds) < 1)
{
    ...
}
```

Или так:

```
public static DateTime TrimMilliseconds(this DateTime dt)
{
    return new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, dt.Minute, dt.Second, 0, dt.Kind);
}

if (date1.TrimMilliseconds().CompareTo(date2.TrimMilliseconds()) == 0)
{
    ...
}
```